# Inserting Data into SQLite Database Using C#

Tags: c#, android, database, sqlite, xamarin

I am creating an `SQLite` Database in `Visual Studio` with `Xamarin` in `C#`.

I should note that this is for `android` only.

I am trying to make it so I am able to insert data into the `SQLite` database but I am unsure how.

I have been following [this](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/data/part_3_using_sqlite_orm/) but I'm still unsure.

Here is the method I am trying to create.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Insert a single ping group into the SQLite ping database.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="pingGroup"></param>
    public void AddUnsynchronizedPing(PingGroup pingGroup)
    {
        // TODO: Add the passed ping group parameter into the SQLite database as new/unsynchronized.
        if (pingGroup != null)
        {
            // Add ping group to the database.
            // Add pings to the database.
            // Maybe one step, maybe done separately.
            // If done separately, must set Ping.PingGroupID to ID of original ping group.
        }
    }
```

For context, here is the entire class.

```
namespace BB.Mobile
{
/// <summary>
/// A class to provide a single interface for interacting with all SQLite data operations for stored tracking points.
/// </summary>
/// 
class DataManager
{
    private SQLiteConnection db = null;

    public DataManager()
    {
        if (this.db == null)
        {
            string dbPath = Path.Combine(
             System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal),
             "bb.db3");

            db = new SQLiteConnection(dbPath);
            db.CreateTable<Ping>();
            db.CreateTable<PingGroup>();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Will compile and return all matching unsynchronized ping data from the SQLite database.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public List<PingGroup> GetUnsynchronizedPings()
    {
        List<PingGroup> unsynchronizedPings = new List<PingGroup>();

        // TODO: Retrieve all unsynchronized pings from the SQLite database and return them to the caller.
        //var pGroup = db.Get<PingGroup>();
        //var pGroupList = db.List<PingGroup>();

        var pGroups = db.Table<PingGroup>();
        foreach (var pGroup in pGroups)
        {

        }

        return unsynchronizedPings;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Insert a single ping group into the SQLite ping database.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="pingGroup"></param>
    public void AddUnsynchronizedPing(PingGroup pingGroup)
    {
        // TODO: Add the passed ping group parameter into the SQLite database as new/unsynchronized.
        if (pingGroup != null)
        {
            // Add ping group to the database.
            // Add pings to the database.
            // Maybe one step, maybe done separately.
            // If done separately, must set Ping.PingGroupID to ID of original ping group.
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Mark all open and unsynchronized pings in the database as synchronized.
    /// </summary>
    public void SetAllPingsSynchronized()
    {
        db.DeleteAll<PingGroup>();
        db.DeleteAll<Ping>();
    }        
}
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To insert the object to sqlite database, you can just use something like:

```
void InsertPing(Ping p)
{
      db.Insert(p);
}


void InsertGroupOfPings(IEnumerable<Ping> pings)
{
   db.InsertAll(pings);
}
```

and to retrieve objects (for example):

```
List<Ping> GetPings()
{  
// I assume here that Ping object has property named Synchronized
    return db.Query<Ping>("select * from Ping where Synchronized = 0");
}
```

The SQLite library creates its tables according to your class definitions, so you can think about the properties of the class as of columns inside the table.